# Active Directory. The following exception occurred while retrieving member distinguishedName: An operations error occurred

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I try to get information from AD using LDAP. Before, I mounted ntds.dit through DSAMAIN at localhost:5000.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ([ADSI]"LDAP://localhost:5000/")
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "Unknown error
(0x80005000)"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ([ADSI]"LDAP://localhost:5000/DC=srv,DC=local")
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "An operations error
occurred.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://localhost:5000/DC=srv,DC=local")
Exception calling "Exists" with "1" argument(s): "An operations error occurred.
"
At line:1 char:1
+ [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://localhost:5000/DC=srv,DC=local")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryServicesCOMException
```

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [adsi]"LDAP://localhost:5000/RootDSE"

distinguishedName : {}
Path              : LDAP://localhost:5000/RootDSE
```

What do I do wrong?